# Transactional with ALTER TABLE. How to implement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, mariadb

There are some groups of queries that include creating tables, fields, etc. How to implement a mechanism by which a group of requests should be executed all, or if somewhere the error was canceled all? That is, the principle of transactionality with ALTER TABLE queries for example (which are committed implicitly)

Comment: DDL statements (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, etc.) automatically commit. Transactions can usually include DML statements (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, others) only. Good question +1. The answer is: it cannot be done.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-statements-that-cause-an-implicit-commit/

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about Commit and Rollback.

However if you are mixing normal SQL with DML (CREATE/ALTER/DROP etc) the DML commands have an implied COMMIT as part of there execution, you cannot avoid it. So this will likely cause you problems if mixed with your normal insert/update/delete type queries

Answer (score 0):

Transactional DML is not possible until MySQL 8.0.  In that version, there is a "Data Dictionary" that is stored in InnoDB tables.  (I don't want to think about the bootstrap required!)  The DD allows, at least in theory, the `ROLLBACK` of DDL actions such as `ALTER` and `DROP TABLE`.  Study the 8.0 docs to see if it does enough for your needs.

In the past (pre-8.0), Many DML operations were at least reasonable "crash safe".  For example, an `ALTER` used to copy the table over, then quickly swap in the new table.  This provided a reasonably good way to recover from, a crash during an `ALTER`.

There have been a lot of major improvements to `ALTER` since 5.6.  Before then, the only really "instant" alter was adding an option to an `ENUM`, and that had caveats.  There are still things that mandate a complete, time-consuming, rebuild of the table -- such as any change to the `PRIMARY KEY`.

DML operations should be minimized; they are not designed for frequent use.